# Equivalent bimodule categories

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, category-theory, bimodules

Let $A,B$ be two rings such that their categories of bimodules are equivalent:
$$A\mathsf{-Bimod} \simeq B\mathsf{-Bimod}$$
What can we say about $A$ and $B$? Are they isomorphic? Are they Morita-equivalent? Probably this has been studied in the literature, so this is primarily a reference request.

Comment: This is equivalent to the condition that $A \otimes A^{op}$ and $B \otimes B^{op}$ are Morita equivalent. I think a more interesting question is to ask that the equivalence respect monoidal structures.

Comment: Yes (to both). But I would like to ask this question first :).

Comment: Are bimodules sufficiently different from modules to deserve a tag? An $(A,B)$-bimodule is merely an $A \otimes B^{op}$-module after all...

Comment: The tensor product of $A$-bimodules is not the tensor product over $A \otimes A^{op}$. The tensor product of free $A$-bimodules is usually not free.

Comment: By the way, there are tags for p-groups, finite groups, cyclic groups, ...

Comment: @Najib: Yes. Modules just form a category, but bimodules form the 1-morphisms in a 2-category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me work over a field $k$ and talk about bimodules over $k$ and $k$-linear categories (so we ask for an equivalence respecting the $k$-linear structure). Then it does not follow that $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent (or isomorphic) over $k$.

The given condition is equivalent to the condition that $A \otimes_k A^{op}$ and $B \otimes_k B^{op}$ are Morita equivalent. If $A, B$ are both central simple algebras over $k$ then both of these algebras are Morita equivalent to $k$, but $A$ and $B$ themselves are Morita equivalent iff they represent the same class in the Brauer group $\text{Br}(k)$. So, for example, we can take the two representatives $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{H}$ of the Brauer group $\text{Br}(\mathbb{R})$.

On the other hand, if $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent, then $\text{Bimod}(A)$ and $\text{Bimod}(B)$ are equivalent even monoidally, because they can be described as the monoidal categories of $k$-linear cocontinuous endofunctors of $\text{Mod}(A)$ and $\text{Mod}(B)$ respectively by Eilenberg-Watts.

Comment: You can get a counterexample over $\mathbb{Z}$ by looking at central simple algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$, since $\otimes_\mathbb{Q}$ coincides with $\otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ for $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras.

Comment: In case the field is algebraically closed(or more generally both algebras are split over the field), the result might be true. At least in characteristic 0.

Comment: If $A$ is a central simple algebra over $k$, isn't the equivalence $U\mapsto U\otimes_kA$ from $\text{Mod}(k)$ to $\text{Bimod}(A)$ always a monoidal equivalence?

Comment: @Jeremy: yes, that sounds right.