# If the monoidal categories of $R$-bimodules and $S$-bimodules are monoidally equivalent, must $R$ and $S$ be Morita equivalent?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, monoidal-categories

If $R$ and $S$ are Morita equivalent rings, then the monoidal categories of $R$-bimodules and $S$-bimodules are monoidally equivalent.

Now, consider the converse:

> **Question**: If the monoidal categories of $R$-bimodules and $S$-bimodules are monoidally equivalent, must $R$ and $S$ be Morita equivalent?

In [Equivalent bimodule categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618661/equivalent-bimodule-categories), it was asked whether the same is true if we merely assume that the categories of bimodules are equivalent as plain categories. The above question is about the stronger hypothesis.